# Is VMWARE_BALLOON (Linux kernel option) intended for guests or hosts?

Tags: linux-kernel, vmware

The kernel configuration option:

> ```
> VMware Balloon Driver (VMWARE_BALLOON) [N/m/y/?] (NEW) ?
>
> CONFIG_VMWARE_BALLOON:
> ```
>
> This is VMware physical memory management driver which acts like a
>   "balloon" that can be inflated to reclaim physical pages by reserving
>   them in the guest and invalidating them in the monitor, freeing up the
>   underlying machine pages so they can be allocated to other guests. The
>   balloon can also be deflated to allow the guest to use more physical
>   memory.
>
> If unsure, say N.
>
> To compile this driver as a module, choose M here: the module will be
>   called vmw_balloon.
>
> ```
> Symbol: VMWARE_BALLOON [=n]
> Type  : tristate
> Prompt: VMware Balloon Driver
>   Defined at drivers/misc/Kconfig:428
>   Depends on: X86 [=y]  
>   Location:
>     -> Device Drivers
>       -> Misc devices
> ```

It's not fully clear, but it sounds like this should be set in the kernel of the guest OS, and not the host.  Is this right?

Comment: Is this a standard-mainstream-kernel? Which version?

Comment: It's 3.5.3 I'm configuring at the moment, and the tree has gentoo patches applied, but I don't believe this option is one of those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is intended to run in the guest OS.

> A small balloon module is loaded into the guest OS as a pseudo-device driver or kernel service. It has no external interface within the guest, and communicates with ESX Server via a private channel. When the server wants to reclaim memory, it instructs the driver to `inflate'' by allocating pinned physical pages within the VM, using appropriate native interfaces. Similarly, the server may`deflate'' the balloon by instructing it to deallocate previously-allocated pages.

(...)

> Our balloon drivers for the Linux, FreeBSD, and Windows operating systems poll the server once per second to obtain a target balloon size, and they limit their allocation rates adaptively to avoid stressing the guest OS.

http://static.usenix.org/events/osdi02/tech/waldspurger/waldspurger_html/node6.html

Comment: Yeah, I've seen explanations of what the balloon is for.  It's just that it requires communication between host and guest, and nothing identifies whether the kernel module is the host or guest piece.  I was thinking guest, because I see no reason the host code would have to be inside the kernel.

Comment: Yes, you was right :)

Comment: @BenVoigt well in the XEN-Dom0 there is balloon-code in the controlling VM (=Dom0) as well. If nothing special is configured, it will see all RAM, not assigned to other VMs as its own RAM. If a VM gets started, the RAM for Dom0 gets reduced...

Comment: @Nils: Yes, but (1) we're discussing VMware, not Xen, and (2) in Xen, DOM0 is a guest (the Xen hypervisor is the host) even if it has more privileges

Comment: @BenVoigt but ESX is a hypervisor, too - or am I wrong?

Comment: @Nils: Well, that's the confusion isn't it.  I'm running VMware Workstation, and the kernel option says nothing at all about ESX.

Comment: @BenVoigt Look at [page 2](http://www.vmware.com/files/pdf/VMware_paravirtualization.pdf). This states that only ESX-server is a hypervisor. So VMWare-workstations seems to be more like ESXi. That would explain all this.

Comment: @Nils: So I may not even have balloon support, even when I compile that into my guest kernel.  That's the problem with succinct documentation -- it leaves out lots of important details.